# Issues with links with url parameters in Sharepoint modern UI( I have to click link twice)

Tags: javascript, jquery, script-editor-webpart

I'm using the modern script editor.
What i'm experiencing is if i use the below

```
<div><a href="/sites/Mysite/SitePages/People.aspx">People</a></div>
```

it works
But when i use with url parameters

```
<div><a href="/sites/Mysite/SitePages/People.aspx?p=k">People</a></div>
```

I have to click twice for it to work

Any ideas as this is just plain html

Comment: All good and came up with an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out and has to reorganize the url string